# How to get new store after dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, dispatch

I want to get a new value from store and use it to do something. How can I do it?

```
const isPass = useSelector((state) => state.checkPopup.result);
const handleDeleteTimeSlot = (id) => {
    dispatch(check_popup());
    //I want get new value isPass and check it.
    if (isPass) {
        let result = dataFake.filter((item) => item._id !== id);
        setDataFake([...result]);
        dispatch(mess_popup());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect()` lifecycle.

```
const isPass = useSelector((state) => state.checkPopup.result);
const handleDeleteTimeSlot = (id) => {
    dispatch(check_popup());
};
React.useEffect(()=>{
  if(isPass) {
    /* do something here */
  }
}, [isPass]);
```